# JWt token cross-validation between nodejs and .NET Core

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

We have an old NodeJS backend generating JWT token when the user signs in. We develop a new C# .NET Core backend. We want to replace the old controller calls with the new one, controller by controller (or method by method if you like). It happens behind the scene, seamlessly.

There can be a situation when the user logs in using the old backend, got a JWT token, then calls a new backend operation, which must accept the JWT token as well. We know the secret of both backend, they can be set to the same, without any problem.

The problem what I see is that setting the same secret is not enough, some different must be, as the nodeJs token is not accepted by the C# side.

The NodeJS code looks like this:

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
function signToken(id, role) {
  return jwt.sign(
     { _id: id, role: role }, 
     config.secrets.session, 
     { expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 }
  );
}
```

The C# code which verifies the token looks as (`Program.cs`)

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Properties[AuthenticationMiddlewareSetKey] = true;
    return app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
}

public static IApplicationBuilder UseAuthorization(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    VerifyServicesRegistered(app);

    app.Properties[AuthorizationMiddlewareSetKey] = true;
    return app.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddlewareInternal>();
}

public static void ConfigureJwtHandler(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var jwtIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").Get<string>();
    var jwtKey = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Key").Get<string>();

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtKey)),
            };

            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5250";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("myUser", policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("role"));
    });
}

...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.ConfigureJwtHandler();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.Run();
```

The auth middleware catches the controller call on C# side, because the API controller is flagged with `[Authorize]`. The error is the following:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>
> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

The `jwtKey` in the C# code and the `config.secrets.session` is set to the very same string value. The NodeJS requires no *issuer*, which is set on the C# side.

How to set up the C# code to accept the JWT token generated by the NodeJs backend? Is it possible?

Comment: Make sure that the C# side uses the same signature algorithm as the NodeJS side. Then you can parse the tokens generated by nodejs and asp.net core to compare whether the structures are the same.

Comment: When generate a token with the nodeJS and C# side, and decode them - both seems HS256...

Comment: Ok, since we can't know more details from the details you provided, it's better to share the minimal sample project which could reproduce the issue, then we can help you to check it deeper.

Comment: Found out that the secret was too short, but the nodejs implementation accepts it and works with it. Validating the nodejs jwt token drops error on the C# side (because of the short secret). When I started to generate jwt token on the C# side it also drops and error with the message "secret key is too short". Setting a longer secret on both side makes it work like a charm!